# Removing < > symbols while typing in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have developed following code. But while typing i need to remove < > these two charectres. Its removing but it removing entire string when we type in middle. I donr want to remove entire string i want remove only < > while typing.

```
 Enter your name: 
<input type="text" id="UserC" onkeyup="rem()">

function rem() {
    var spclChars = "<>"; // specify special characters 
    var content = document.getElementById("UserC").value;
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        if (spclChars.indexOf(content.charAt(i)) != -1) {

            document.getElementById("UserC").value = "";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code it's working perfectly...

```
    $(document).on('keypress', "#inputid", function(e) {

        var check_val = $("#inputid").val();

        if ((e.which == 60 || e.which == 62)) {   // < ascii value is 60 and > ascii value is 62
            console.log(check_val);
            // $(this).attr("placeholder", "digits only");
            // $(this).addClass("alert-danger");
            $(this).val(check_val);
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("alert-danger");
        }
    });
```

Comment: without using Jquery Bro

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for that:

```js
 var str = 'hello<name>'
    
    function rem(string) {
      return string.replace(/<|>/g, '')
    }
    console.log(rem(str))
```

this will output helloname.

Comment: i need to remove while typing thestring

Comment: If so, why don't you call the function in the correspodning event handler? That should do the trick.